# Drag and Drop to explorer causing invalid FORMATETC (DV_E_FORMATETC) error

Tags: c#, com, drag-and-drop, windows-explorer

I'm trying to use [this excellent example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/DataObjectEx.aspx) to implement dropping virtual files into Windows Explorer. However, I'm stymied by this error. Towards the bottom, inside `void System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject.GetData(ref System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FORMATETC formatetc, out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STGMEDIUM medium)` on the first call to `((System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject)this).GetDataHere(ref formatetc, ref medium);` I'm getting back a `DV_E_FORMATETC` error. As far as I can tell, all the elements of the FORMATETC struct that are being passed in are valid: cfFormat is "Shell IDList Array" (-16141), ptd is 0, dwAspect is DVASPECT_CONTENT, lindex is -1, and tymed is TYMED_HGLOBAL. I'm kind of confused how there'd be a problem anyway, since this was generated by explorer.

I know very little about COM interaction, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reimplementing about half of IDataObject, it turns out that error code is caused by not supporting "Shell IDList Array" in GetDataPresent().